# Tracking email opens with Amazon SES, SNS and SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I'm trying to track email opens through Amazon. I'm using Amazon SES to send out the emails.

I've followed the instructions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/event-publishing-add-event-destination-sns.html

I've created a queue in SQS and I've made an SNS topic with a subscription with SQS as protocol with the the SQS queue endpoint.

So, I've created a configuration set to track the Open and Click actions and set the destination to SNS. I've used Amazon SES Default Domain. I'm also adding the necessary header when sending the emails such that the configuration set is used.

My understanding is that Opens and Clicks should get back to the Amazon cloud, routed to the SNS configuration set -> caught by the SNS -> forwarded in the SQS queue.

In my emails I see a tracking image for Open events and links are changed for tracking Click events (both are something with awstrack.me....)

However, I don't get anything in the SQS queue. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to include send and recieve events as well so that we could find if its not working for open and click event or not working for anything at all

Comment: thanks for the reply. I also enabled Send for the email configuration set, but I still don't see any messages in the queue

Comment: you have to debug it piece by piece remove that sqs part for now and let sns send you sms or email as a subscription and see if it works

Comment: I got it! I made a mistake. see the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I found what I did wrong. I subscribed to the SQS queue from the SNS topic. The correct way is to subscribe from the SQS queue to the SNS topic (right click on the queue and click "Subscribe queue to SNS Topic")

Comment: Thank you for the tip!

Comment: Glad to be of help